# Prevent double border when joining multiple html table - border-collapse not working

Tags: css, html-table, border

Please help me to prevent double border when joining multiple html table. I have tried to use "border-collapse:collapse" but its not working. Still border is double between two table.

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
     <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Heading-1</td>
      <td>Heading-2</td>
      <td>Heading-3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Heading-4</td>
      <td>Heading-5</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Heading-6</td>
      <td>Heading-7</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
     <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Heading-1</td>
      <td>Heading-2</td>
      <td>Heading-3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Heading-4</td>
      <td>Heading-5</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Heading-6</td>
      <td>Heading-7</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
<table style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="3">Heading-1</td>
  <td>Heading-2</td>
  <td>Heading-3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Heading-4</td>
  <td>Heading-5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Heading-6</td>
  <td>Heading-7</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add  `margin-top: -1px;` to your `table`.

```css
table {
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Heading-1</td>
    <td>Heading-2</td>
    <td>Heading-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Heading-4</td>
    <td>Heading-5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Heading-6</td>
    <td>Heading-7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Heading-1</td>
    <td>Heading-2</td>
    <td>Heading-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Heading-4</td>
    <td>Heading-5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Heading-6</td>
    <td>Heading-7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Heading-1</td>
    <td>Heading-2</td>
    <td>Heading-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Heading-4</td>
    <td>Heading-5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Heading-6</td>
    <td>Heading-7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```